# Как выровнять ячейки в таблице с объединенными ячейками?

Tags: html, css

Создал таблицу и разделил некоторые ячейки на две и три. При разделении поломались пропорции ячеек. Они должны быть одинаковы, а получается так, что где ячейки объединены - не объединенные ячейки стали больше, другие меньше в высоте или ширине. Ниже то как сейчас, как должно быть и код.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
table {
  width: 70%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Txt</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td rowspan="2">txt</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="3" align="right">txt</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td rowspan="2" align="right">txt</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2" align="right">txt</td>
    <td></td>
    <td align="right">txt</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td rowspan="3">txt</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>txt</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td align="right">txt</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td align="right">txt</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `padding: 10;` - кто вас такому научил?

Comment: Интернет. А что не так с этим?

Comment: Если вы поставите текст в каждую из ячеек, то увидите, что все отображается как нужно. А у вас сейчас высота ячеек с текстом в принципе больше, потому как этот самый текст добавляет эту высоту - отсюда и такие "скачки"

Comment: А как это исправить? Мне нужно чтобы все было ровно.

Comment: Ну вы же эту таблицу чем-то заполнять будете? И дополните вопрос скриншотом или примером того, что должно получиться на выходе

Comment: Нет. Все так и останется, текст этот окончательный.

Comment: Обновил вопрос. Добавил требуемый результат.

Comment: Установите width:14.285% для td. И height или min-height так же для td

Comment: Я так понимаю padding: 10 убирать?

Comment: Я же поправил в вашем коде - padding:10px;